# mysql workbench - how to print on one page

Tags: mysql-workbench

I use 2 pages in the diagram properties for my diagram.

[image]

However, I want to print the whole diagram on a single dinA4 paper.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

1. File > Page Setup...  set page the most suitable for your diagram.
2. **File > Print to File...**
3. Than just print PDF file on your printer in A4 format

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if your printer driver supports printing multiple pages on a single one. Scan your printer settings for that.

If that doesn't work you can try setting a larger paper type in `File -> Page Setup...`. For instance if you have 2 A4 pages in your model set the paper type to A3 which will place your model on a single page. Then print this page scaled down on A4 (or use and A3 printer if you have).

Comment: I can copy 2 pages on one sheet - but then I have a white stripe in the middle of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know from which version of MySQL WorkBench exactly this is possible, but at least in version 6.3 you can simply do :

1. File > Page setup... > set your page preferences
2. File > Export > Export as single Page PDF...
3. Open the generated PDF file with your favourite PDF reader and print it